# How can I get total number of records for server side paging from a WCF Service in Silverlight 5?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to do server side paging through my WCF Service. My code gets only the 50 records and displays them but the total is 57 records and I am not able to page to the 2nd page to view them. This is my service code:

```
<OperationContract()>
    Public Function QueryUsersForGroup(
        ByVal authentication As AuthenticationArgs,
        ByVal group As Guid,
        ByVal skip As Integer,
        ByVal take As Integer) As ResponseArgs(Of User())

        Dim exception As ExceptionArgs = Nothing

        If AuthenticationService.CheckPermissions(
            authentication,
            exception,
            PermissionType.AdministerUserAccounts) Then

            Dim model As CscModel = DataHelper.CreateModel()
            Dim currentGroup = model.Groups.FirstOrDefault(Function(row) row.Id.Equals(group))
            If currentGroup Is Nothing Then Return New ResponseArgs(Of User())(New User() {})

            ' This only returns 50 records since take is 50 from my callback
            Return New ResponseArgs(Of User())(currentGroup.Users.Ship(skip).Take(take).ToArray())

        Else

            Return New ResponseArgs(Of User())(exception)

        End If

    End Function
```

How could I be able to pass the total count of the records and also only the 50 records that will be displayed at a time?

Comment: Too bad this is VB... what is the problem? the 2nd page should be skip 50 (Page Size * (Page Number-1)) take 50 (Page Size)?

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 the problem is that the total count of the items isn't being passed, only the first 50 items and the Next Page arrow is never active to page to the next 7 items. How would you do it in C#?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to assist, but I see you have found out how.  I think for next time, you can provide more information on what "ResponseArgs" was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to pass the total count of my records. I just added a second parameter to my

```
ResponseArgs(of User())(curretGroup.Users.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToArray(), totalCount)
```

and it worked! Of course I had to modify my ResponseArgs class to allow 2 parameters as well.